# Horizontally and vertically centered object doesn't work in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, css-position

I have an `<img>` which is centred horizontally and vertically, and it works in Chrome and Safari but unfortunately not in Firefox. In Firefox the `<img>` is centred horizontally but not vertically. How do I fix this? Does it have to do with the jquery animation?

You can see an example of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/amagdk/kan94az0/

**HTML**

```
<img src="hover-kitty.png" alt="Hover Kitty">
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var hoverkitty = $("img");
   function hover() {
       hoverkitty.animate({top:'+=20'}, 1000);
       hoverkitty.animate({top:'-=20'}, 1000, hover);
   }
   hover();
});
```

Comment: Looks like if you comment out `//hover()` the image centers, so it seems to be an issue with that. Is there a reason you're incrementing the values? http://jsfiddle.net/kan94az0/39/

Comment: Aha, ugh then I am even more clueless how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create something that will work in firefox. You can use `padding-top` instead of `top`:

```js
var hoverkitty = $("img");

function hover() {
    hoverkitty.animate({
        'padding-top': '+=20'
    }, 1000);
    hoverkitty.animate({
        'padding-top': '-=20'
    }, 1000, hover);
}

hover();
```

```css
img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://itu.dk/people/akam/ta_challenge/hover-kitty.png" alt="Hover Kitty">
```